# error: ‘xxx’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have a weird problem I don't understand.  I am copying over some C code to a C++ class and cannot get past this error "does not name a type" ... I hope I copied enough code for this to make sense, original program is ~1000 lines

Error is .. error: ‘HTTPContext’ does not name a type

The line of the error is "**HTTPContext MainWindow::*find_rtp_session_with_url(const char *url, const char *session_id)**"

className.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:

     typedef struct HTTPContext{
         int fd;
     }HTTPContext;

     HTTPContext *find_rtp_session_with_url(const char *url,
                                              const char *session_id);
};
```

className.cpp

```
#include "className.h"

HTTPContext MainWindow::*find_rtp_session_with_url(const char *url,
                                          const char *session_id)
{
     HTTPContext *rtp_c;  

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTTPContext` is declared in class scope, so to use in the function definition in global scope you need specify it explicitly:

```
MainWindow::HTTPContext *MainWindow::find_rtp_session_with_url...
```

Comment: This works on getting rid of that error, but now within the find_rtp_session_with_url function  "error: ‘HTTPContext’ was not declared in this scope ...

Comment: Are you sure the code is exactly like that? That is, the function is, indeed, `MainWindow::find_rtp_session_wirh_url` and you use `HTTPContext` in it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to say

```
MainWindow::HTTPContext* MainWindow::find_rtp_session_with_url( ...
```

since it's an inner class. Also you don't have to use `typedef` there:

```
struct HTTPContext {
    int fd;
};
```

is enough to name a type in C++.